# Seaborn residplot for multiple regression

Tags: python, seaborn

When passing columns to seaborn.residplot, is it possible to pass more then one IV variable (in the case of a multiple regression analysis)?

I'm tried some conventional methods ['IV1','IV2'] etc.. but they don't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, it does not work for multiple independent variables (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.residplot.html).

The only way, in my opinion, to plot the residual of a multiple regression would be to fit the linear model by yourself and then extract the residual and plot it using seaborn.

Linear regression can be fit using `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`.

Comment: Thanks! As suggested, I found a similar way https://medium.com/@emredjan/emulating-r-regression-plots-in-python-43741952c034